# Excel - Search and Re-copied texts from two tables

Tags: excel, vba

- I Want to : **Search and Re-copied texts from two tables** => **Excel**

**Example + Result** => Show pic that's what I want 

=> Show pic 
 [image: Click show pic]

Comment: you want to do this in VBA ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the picture, put the following formula in cell C5:

```
 =VLOOKUP(B5,$E$5:$F$9,2,FALSE)
```